# h3 s with spaces between and same line

Tags: css

Hi i have three h3 (masthead-brand 0-2)

now i saw on the internet that display inline block makes them on the same line, but my idea was having them in the same line AND having spaces between that: masthead is on the left corner of the website, masthead1 is in the center, and masthead2 is in the right corner of the website.
How could i do it?

```css
.masthead-brand {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #3434f3;
}

.masthead-brand1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.masthead-brand2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: crimson;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <div>
    <h3 class="masthead-brand">Held </h3>
    <h3 class="masthead-brand1"> oder</h3>
    <h3 class="masthead-brand2"> Schurke?</h3>
  </div>
  
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
      <li class="active"><a  [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a  routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a></li>
      <li><a  routerLink="/villains">Schurken</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <p class="lead">
    <a href="#" class="kämpfeMethode">Kämpfe jetzt!</a>
  </p>
    
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the related html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add any class to h3' wrapper div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <h3 class="masthead-brand">Held</h3>
   <h3 class="masthead-brand1">oder</h3>
   <h3 class="masthead-brand2">Schurke?</h3>
</div>
```

and make it flex:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Why not make the "wrapper" the h3, and use span for the different words? This way, robots still understand it's content.

Answer (score 0):

It's semantically wrong to use 3 seperate headlines.

You should rather use one headline and format its contents.

Here I did it with the help of `span` elements.
The positioning is done with the help of `flex`. Flex offers the property to justify its contents just as you need it:

```css
.masthead-brand {
    color: #3434f3;
}
    
.masthead-brand1 {
}
    
.masthead-brand2 {
    color: crimson;
}
    
h3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
h3 span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3>
    <span class="masthead-brand">Held</span>
    <span class="masthead-brand1">oder</span>
    <span class="masthead-brand2">Schurke?</span>
</h3>
```